# Spark-rdd manipulating data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a sample data like below:

```
UserId,ProductId,Category,Action
1,111,Electronics,Browse
2,112,Fashion,Click
3,113,Kids,AddtoCart
4,114,Food,Purchase
5,115,Books,Logout
6,114,Food,Click
7,113,Kids,AddtoCart
8,115,Books,Purchase
9,111,Electronics,Click
10,112,Fashion,Purchase
3,112,Fashion,Click
```

I need to generate list of users who are interested in either “Fashion” category or “Electronics” category but not in both categories. User is interested if he/she has performed any of these actions (Click / AddToCart / Purchase) using spark/scala code I have done up till below:

```
val rrd1 = sc.textFile("/user/harshit.kacker/datametica_logs.csv")
val rrd2 = rrd1.map( x=> {
     | val c = x.split(",")
     | (c(0).toInt , x)})

val rrd3 = rrd1.filter(x=> x.split(",")(2) == "Fashion" || x.split(",")(2) == "Electronics")
val rrd4 = rrd3.filter(x=> x.split(",")(3)== "Click" || x.split(",")(3)=="Purchase" || x.split(",")(3)=="AddtoCart")
rrd4.collect.foreach(println)

2,112,Fashion,Click
9,111,Electronics,Click
10,112,Fashion,Purchase
3,112,Fashion,Click
4,111,Electronics,Click
19,112,Fashion,Click
9,112,Fashion,Purchase
2,112,Fashion,Click
2,111,Electronics,Click
1,112,Fashion,Purchase
```

now I have to work on "to generate list of users who are interested in either “Fashion” category or “Electronics” category ***but not in both categories***" this italic part  and get desired output as :

```
10,Fashion
3,Fashion
4,Electronics
19,Fashion
1,Fashion
```

means userId having **Fashion and Electronics** as category should be eliminated. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Do you only want to use RDDs?

Comment: I have does same question using hive , so spark-sql can also be done .. so now i am trying to do using spark-rdd or may be scala ? what do you suggest any other way we can slve this problem ?

Comment: SparkSQL gives you a much easier way

Comment: yes I am trying with spark-sql

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this using Spark Scala ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by parsing the input text file in to tuples:

```
val srcPath = "/user/harshit.kacker/datametica_logs.csv"

// parse test file in to tuples:
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(srcPath)
val rows = rdd.map(line => line.split(",")).map(row => (row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3)))
val header = rows.first
// drop the header:
val logs = rows.filter(row => row != header)
```

Filter the RDD by interest criteria:

```
val interests = logs.filter(log =>
  List("Click", "AddtoCart", "Purchase").contains(log._4)
)
```

Filter for fashion and electronics separately:

```
val fashion = interests.filter(row => row._3 == "Fashion")
val electronics = interests.filter(row => row._3 == "Electronics")
```

Find the common user IDs between fashion and electronics:

```
val fashionIds = fashion.map(_._1).distinct
val electronicsIds = electronics.map(_._1).distinct
val commonIds = fashionIds.intersection(electronicsIds).collect()
```

Combine the fashion and electronics rows and filter the ids common between both:

```
val finalRdd = (fashion ++ electronics)
  .filter(log => !commonIds.contains(log._1))
  .map(log => (log._1, log._3))
  .distinct()
```

Edit: Using DataFrame

```
// using dataframes:

val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(srcPath)
val interestDf = df.where($"Action".isin("Click", "Purchase", "AddToCart"))
val fashionDf = interestDf.where($"Category" === "Fashion")
val electronicsDf = interestDf.where($"Category" === "Electronics")

val joinDf = electronicsDf.alias("e").join(fashionDf.alias("f"), Seq("UserId"), "outer")
  .where($"e.Category".isNull || $"f.Category".isNull)

val finalDf = joinDf.select($"UserId", when($"e.Category".isNull, $"f.Category").otherwise($"e.Category").as("Category")).distinct
```